# Why does std::forward_list::empty has [[nodiscard]] while std::forward_list::max_size doesn't?

Tags: c++, c++17, standards, api-design, forward-list

In the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list) of `std::forward_list`, there are two member functions:

1. `[[nodiscard]] bool empty() const noexcept;`
2. `size_type max_size() const noexcept;`

What makes me surprised is:

**Why does `empty` has `[[nodiscard]]` while `max_size` doesn't?**

Comment: I'd guess the committee hasn't got around to it yet. It appears all the [empty](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/nodiscard) methods got it at once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is two-part:

1. There is no way to confuse the query "what is the maximum size?" expressed as `.maximum_size()` with anything else, while you could confuse the query "is it empty?" expressed as `.empty()` with the command "empty it!", which got the name `.clear()`.
2. `[[nodiscard]]` is new, and has not been applied everywhere applicable in the standard library (to date). C++20 adds some places, but still isn't anywhere near comprehensive.

Comment: Well, I can imagine someone could read `max_size()` to mean resizing to the biggest supported size. I'm thinking of how beginners sometimes write `char my_input[99999];` or something like it to "be big enough, just in case". Someone might think it's a good idea to allocate very large buffers for their application and see `max_size` as a feature designed for their purpose. Edit : Granted it seems like a rarer mistake than getting `empty()` wrong.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Nice demonstration that absolute rookies can be truely unbelievable.